# Why use multiple filters output thousands value, use one or two filter can output normal value?

Tags: sensors, c, hardware, analog

### Problem

If the loop runs only one simulated pin and uses a filter, it will output normally (analog 1600~2200, filter 0~500), but creating an array to store multiple filtered simulated pin values will cause problems, and the output will be abnormal (10000~80000).

[image: 2022-04-15--15-00-07_fps=8_scale=720_max_colors=128|690x298]

If analog read six sensors, and their value is 1600~2200.

It used the code below.

```
#include "EMGFilters.h"
#define SERIAL_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 4096 //修改串口接收缓冲区大小为2048
const int SensorInputPin[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
EMGFilters myFilter[6];
SAMPLE_FREQUENCY sampleRate = SAMPLE_FREQ_500HZ;
NOTCH_FREQUENCY humFreq = NOTCH_FREQ_50HZ;

void setup()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        myFilter[i].init(sampleRate, humFreq, true, true, true);
    }
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(250000);
    analogReadResolution(12);
}
void loop()
{
    long time = millis();
    int x[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int analog[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
    {
        //x[index] = myFilter[index].update(analogRead(SensorInputPin[index]));
        analog[index] = analogRead(SensorInputPin[index]);
    }
    while ((millis() - time) < 2)
    {
        delayMicroseconds(100);
    }
    Serial.printf("filter:%d %d %d %d %d %d analog:%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5],analog[0],analog[1],analog[2],analog[3],analog[4],analog[5]);
    Serial1.printf("<%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d>", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]);
}
```

Change `index<6` to `index<2`, and uncomment `\\x[index] = myFilter[index].update(analogRead(SensorInputPin[index]));`

It will be a normal output using two inputs and filters.

[image: 2022-04-15--15-15-26_fps=8_scale=720_max_colors=128|690x341]

But changing `index=0;index<2` to `index=0;index<6` will be abnormal output.
[image: 2022-04-15--15-29-32_fps=8_scale=720_max_colors=28|690x323]

If changing to `index=3;index<4` or `index=2;index<3`...etc, it will be normal output:
[image: 2022-04-15--15-15-43_fps=8_scale=720_max_colors=128|690x459]

Sketch:
[image: image|470x500]
[image: image|667x500]
[image]
[image]
[image]

XIAO MCU schematic in the HTML: https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Seeeduino-XIAO/res/Seeeduino-XIAO-v1.0-SCH-191112.pdf

I don't have a sensor schematic.

Filter code: https://github.com/oymotion/EMGFilters/blob/master/EMGFilters.cpp

I hope each simulation output to look like the first Gif(normal output), what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You need one filter per input...?

Comment: You didn't provide any context on what you are actually measuring, but I second Majenko with the guess, that you need one filter per analog input. Also I don't really understand your problem description. If this is because of the language barrier, maybe someone can help you, who speaks english better, and help with the wording of the question.

Comment: @Majwnko yes. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @chrisl I'm sorry, I may not be as fluent in English as my mother tongue. I hope each simulation output to look like the first Gif.

Comment: You currently use only one filter: `myFilter`. But you can define multiple filters in the same way and put them into an array for use in the for loop. Something like this: `EMGFilters myFilters[6];` (define an array of 6 EMGFilters). In `setup()`: `for(int i=0;i<6;i++) myFilters[i].init(sampleRate, humFreq, true, true, true);`. And in the for loop: `envelops[i * 6 + x] = square(myFilters[x].update(analogRead(SensorInputPin[x])));`.

Comment: But I think you also need to think about what you are outputting. Currently you try to output the values of individual sensors in a new line each. The serial plotter interprets this as new datapoints of the same signal, though actually you have 6 data points, one for each signal. I think the Serial Plotter supports plotting multiple lines, when you print the datapoints in one line seperated by a space.

Comment: @chrisl I have tried to create a filter for the simulated output, but the output is still abnormal(The post has been updated and the picture has been uploaded). The loop function outputs normally only if it has only one line of instruction`square(myFilter.update(analogRead(SensorInputPin[per input])))`. I don't understand why only one line should output normally.

Comment: @chrisl I found using third analog input case error, what do you think is the reason?   I measured the third analog input separately and found no problems. It seems that as long as I use the third one, no matter what the third analog pin is, it producing thousands of values. The issue has been updated.

Comment: What Arduino board you are using? You are assuming that each integer is 2-byte long, this is true if you are using an Arduino Uno, but it will not be the case if you are using an STM32 or SAMD-based Arduino, for those, an `Int` is 4-bytes.

Comment: @chrisl Hello, I reconstructed the post.

Comment: @hcheung OK. I have been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the filter library you are using. [It has already been
reported](https://github.com/oymotion/EMGFilters/issues/3) (by you, maybe?).

As Majenko and chrisl suggested in comments, the crux of the problem is
that you need one filter per input channel. Using multiple instances of
`EMGFilters` seems like the obvious solution. Alas, the library keeps
the filter state in global variables, which essentially means your six
filter objects all reference the same actual filter.

Comment: Yes. It's my Issue. How do I prevent referencing global variables of the same filter? Need to reference "EMGFilters1.h","EMGFilters2.h"...etc?

Comment: @C.SH.K: No. You should fix the library, or wait for the authors to fix it. If you want to do it yourself, just turn the filter state into instance data. C.f. my comment to your issue.

Comment: @C.SH.K: Or you may use the branch from [this pull request](https://github.com/oymotion/EMGFilters/pull/4).

Comment: Thank you! Solved the immediate problem!

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckaNR.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcRR.gif)After using your file, some pins have a strange place, some emG output tens of thousands of values, some normal output. Before, with the raw filter code, it would print like this[Before index=0;index<1...etc](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/0/5/8/05885f12cbba1c227d4f4349a169a8979a2f8caa.gif)

Comment: Oh. Just bad sensor contactThe sensor AREA I bought is too large, so it is not easy for the dry electrode to fully contact the skin when touching the arm, which is prone to baseline drift.